# After flashing from SP Flash tool, phone won't boot up

Tags: huawei, device-firmware

**Device: Huawei Honor Hol-U19**

It was bootloop so I tried flashing the firmware sing SP Flash tool. But now, the phone won't even start/boot to it's logo. I can't feel any vibration afte pressing the power button or any of the buttons. Can someone help me?

Comment: remove battery and check if preloader drivers detected (pops up for a second when connecting)

Comment: I can flash it again and again. But wont boot up

Comment: won't boot up, or completely dead? what exactly did you flash and how? make a readback of boot.img. patch it with Magisk Manager and flash it back. do not flash preloader. do not 'Firmware upgrade' or 'Format all'

Comment: I used Format All + Download. Then the phone is dead but can still be detected by SP Flash tool. Ho do I fix that?

Comment: You need another device for cloning. You have erased important partitions which are not in included in ROM

Comment: Can't I get online tools for that without the other device?

Comment: open scatter file and change all partitions to is_download = true, find a stock ROM which includes all partitions, flash all partitions except preloader, then find a tool for restoring IMEI (maybe if you read all 246 pages you find solution) https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64880361&postcount=1250

Comment: Do you have the list of all partitions needed? @alecxs

Comment: look inside the scatter file on post #2

Comment: @alecxs last question. Should I use Format All + Download this time, or Download Only?

Comment: @alecxs now the checksum does not match the scatter

Comment: i recommend Download only. just delete the checksum

Answer (score 1):

LG hold both volume button and power button same time fir about 20 seconds, worked for me tho cricket had no clue.